# Remove extra character from System Path variable using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

A previous batch file that we used had an accidental extra **"** in one of the scripts, so now anything that gets added on is not being seen.

I'm unable to find a good answer as to how to remove the extra **`"`** from the Path variable.  Any advice?

Current Path:

```
%M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0";C:\Program Files\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin
```

As you'll see, after the *Powershell\v1.0,* there is an extra **`"`**.

Any advice would be more than appreciated.  I've been banging my head on this for quite awhile.

Comment: Trying to create a new batch file that could be run to take care of this without any one going into their system variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I have a variable PATH that I create to hold an environment variable called %PATH%, this is what I would write.

SET PATH=%PATH:"=%

DOS string substitution syntax is a colon followed by the substring to replace then an equal sign followed by the text to replace the substring with.  So what the :"= does is replace all " in the %PATH% variable with nothing.

```
SET MYPATH=F:\cyntrx\deploy\scripts\automated_tasks\ReportIftaVehicleCode\
ECHO MYPATH
SET PATH=%MYPATH:\=%
ECHO PATH
```

In order to actually change the Windows %PATH% environment variable instead of just "fixing" the environment variable for the batch file itself to use, then use the setx /m command in the batch file.  **IMPORTANT:  The change will not be shown by the ECHO command until the command prompt is closed and restarted.**

System variable:

```
setx path "%PATH:"=%" /m
```

User variable:

```
setx path "%PATH:"=%"
```

Comment: That's very close to where I was:
Set PATH=%PATH:"=% 

However, if you open a new CMD window and run Echo %PATH% again, it's back.  It seems that that method doesn't save the edit?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Right, echo PATH, not %PATH%.  PATH is your modified string. (updated my answer to show)

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now.  Your batch file is actually trying to update the environment variable, not "fixing" the environment variable for its own use.  In that case it's the setx /m command.

Comment: Yes :)  Sorry for the confusion on my part.  The environment variable is what needs to get changed on all the servers that had this problem.

Comment: How would you write that?  I'm getting invalid syntax saying it is not allowed more than '2' times?

Comment: Glad to help!  If this was what worked could you please accept the answer so that others can find it?

Answer (score 1):

System in Control Panel - Advanced System Setings - Advanced tab - Environmental Variables.